# Is there an analytical solution to this differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am not very knowledgeable in the field so I apologize in advance if this question might look naive.
But is there an analytical solution to a differential equation that looks like this :

$$\frac {\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} = a\cdot v(t) - \mathrm{b}\cdot y $$

My issue here is the function $v(t)$ and how I should deal with it.

Thanks

Comment: what denotes $y(t)$?

Comment: I meant  $y(t)$ is $y$ (edited)

Comment: i don't understand your equation

Comment: What is the unknown ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of the homogeneous equation

$$y'(t)=-by(t)$$ is easily found to be $y(t)=Ce^{-bt}$.

Then by variation of the constant, $y(t)=c(t)e^{-bt}$ yields

$$c'(t)e^{-bt}-bc(t)e^{-bt}=av(t)-bc(t)e^{-bt}$$

or

$$c'(t)=av(t)e^{bt},$$

$$c(t)=\int av(t)e^{bt}dt+C,$$

$$y(t)=\left(\int av(t)e^{bt}dt+C\right)e^{-bt}.$$

Obviously, the equation has an analytical solution when the integral has one.

---

If the unknown is the function $v$, then

$$v(t)=\frac{y'(t)+by(t)}a.$$

Comment: Thanks I think I get it

Answer (score 0):

Yes,there is:

$$y(t)=ce^{-bt}+ae^{-bt}\int_1^t e^{bx} \nu(x)\,dx$$

where $c$ is a constant.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, your equation is of the from
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}y} = -by(x) + h(x) $$

A solution then is available (http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0103.pdf, just setting $g(x) = 1, f_1(x) = -b , f_0(x)=h(x) $)

$$ y = Ce^{-bx} + e^{-bx} \int e^{-bx} h(x)\mathrm{d}x $$

Comment: Why downvoted??